# Simple way to check if a string "Like" another with jokers

Tags: php, regex

I'm looking for a function that do the same as SQL LIKE statements :

```
$match = match('abcdefg', 'a_c*fg');
```

where "_" represent one char and "*" multiple.

I need to replace theses char with a regex part like ".+" for "*" but i should before it escape regex chars with preg_quote excepts theses two "_" and "*".

Is there a simple way to do it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

take a look at [fnmatch](http://it.php.net/fnmatch) function

OR

```
like('goo*','google.com');      -->  strpos('goo','google.com') === 0
```

The next one, you can use strpos:

```
like('*gl*','google.com');      -->  strpos('gl', 'google.com') !== false;
```

The next you can just use equals:

```
like('google.com','google.com') -->  'google.com' == 'google.com'
```

Of course, you can use regex for all of them:

```
like('goo*','google.com');      -->  preg_match('#^goo.*$#','google.com') 
like('*gl*','google.com');      -->  preg_match('#^.*gl.*$#', 'google.com');
like('google.com','google.com') -->  preg_match('#^google\.com$#', 'google.com')
```

to convert your patterns to regex, place a ^ at the beginning, and a $ at the end, then replace * with .* and escape .s.